# Spotfire - Identify each time a value changes in a particular pattern for a particular type

Tags: spotfire

Apologies for the bad title, I'm struggling to describe exactly what I;m trying to do (which has also made it difficult to search for an existing answer.

I have a series of date with the columns "Asset", "Time", and a "State" that is a calculated column that changes based on several other values. The data is source from a constant, and non-regular stream of data (though in the table below I have created a sample of timestamps that are regular).

The below table shows the source data ("Asset", "Time" and "State"), as well as an intended calculated column "Event" that tracks each time an event starts. I do not simply want to count the number of times an "Asset" has a Bad "State", but identify each time an "Asset" changes from a "State" of Good to a state of Bad (note in the real data there is a large number of different states, but the pattern I'm trying to identify is consistent).

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| Asset |   Time   | State | Event |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
|     1 | 12:00:00 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:00 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:01 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:01 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:02 | Bad   |     1 |
|     2 | 12:00:02 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:03 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:03 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:04 | Bad   |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:04 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:05 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:05 | Bad   |     1 |
|     2 | 12:00:06 | Bad   |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:06 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:07 | Bad   |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:07 | Good  |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:08 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:08 | Bad   |     1 |
|     2 | 12:00:09 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:09 | Bad   |     0 |
|     2 | 12:00:10 | Good  |     0 |
|     1 | 12:00:10 | Good  |     0 |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I intend to create a chart for this data to show how many times an event occurs for a particular asset per day. I figured the easiest way to do that is to have a column that counts a 1 when the event starts, and then sum this column over the dates to create the visualisation.

My idea was for a calculated column that picks up when the "State" is bad, and then checks to see if the previous state for that "Asset" was good, and set as a 1 if so. I have so far been unable to find a way to identify what the value was for a previous row entry for a particular "Asset".

Note that there are roughly 100 (or more) individual "Asset" entries, so creating an individual calculated column to track each would not be feasible. I am also using Spotfire 7.1.

Thanks in advance, and sorry again if the way I've written this is confusing.

Comment: I think this article might help: https://www.tibco.com/blog/2016/09/12/solving-a-common-problem-using-the-rowid-function/